# emplace lambda task that used packaged_task into a queue

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So I have this enqueue implementation for a threadpool

```
     template <typename F, typename... Args>
        auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
            using return_type = decltype(f(args...));
            auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<return_type()>>(
                    std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
            );
            auto result = task->get_future();
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queue_mutex);
                if (m_stop)
                    throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");
                m_tasks.emplace([task]() { (*task)(); });
            }
            m_condition.notify_one();
            return result;
        }
```

So far so good, but I would like to avoid using memory allocation and not use the make_shared.

So I change it to this:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
    auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
        using return_type = decltype(f(args...));
        auto task = std::packaged_task<return_type()>(
                std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );
        auto result = task.get_future();
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queue_mutex);
            if (m_stop)
                throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");
            m_tasks.emplace([task = std::move(task)]() mutable { task(); });
        }
        m_condition.notify_one();
        return result;
    }
```

As far as I know, there is no copy here.
the task should be moved into the lambda and the lambda should be moved into the queue but still, I get this error:

> use of deleted function ‘std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes
> ...)>::packaged_task(const std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&)
> [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]’    38 |
> m_tasks.emplace(task mutable { task(); });

what I understand is that I'm trying to copy the packaged_task and its copy constructor is deleted.

here you can play with the full code

https://godbolt.org/z/bEsPfabz6

thanks!

Comment: You are not showing the cause of the error in your question. It is because of the type of `m_tasks` which is `std::queue<std::function<void()>>`. `std::function` works only with copyable callables.